# Push Remote Notification to ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I have a problem am trying to solve.
I have a tabbar as my `rootViewController` defined like this
`window?.rootViewController = MainTabViewController()`
I need to push to a viewController From a remote push notification with the snippet below, but my app crash with `cannot cast MainTabViewController to UINavigationViewController` I know I cannot do that cast since MainTabViewController is not embedded in a NavigationViewController. What is the best way to approach this?

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let type = userInfo["type"] as? String, let data = userInfo["data"] as? String, let title = userInfo["title"] as? String {
        let params = ["type": type, "data": data, "title": title]
        Analytics.AddEvent(title: "Notification Open", params: params)

        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.title = ""
        let navVC = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        NSLog("Controller Type: \(navVC.description)")
        navVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        navVC.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
        if type == "category_product"{
            //Show product list
            var params = [String: String]()
            params["CategoryName"] = title
            params["CategoryId"] = data
            Analytics.AddEvent(title: "Category Opened", params: params)

            let vc = ProductListingVC()
            vc.categoryName = title
            vc.category_id = data
            vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
            navVC.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: Why not embedding the tabBar in a navigation controller?

Comment: @Yitzchak the tabBar children have there navigation controller, the Tabbar nav controller covers it.

Comment: What do you want to do? navigate to a VC without tab bar? Or navigate to VC inside one of the tabs?

Comment: no, the VC is not one of the Tabs, but I want to push to it from TabBarController, since TabBarController is the rootViewController

Comment: After the push -> The tabs should be visible or not?

Comment: It can or may not, the important thing is that I get the VC I am pushing to be displayed and also have a back button to go back to the whichever VC is in the stack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160707/discussion-between-yitzchak-and-simpimind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `tabBarController` as `rootViewController` and you are type casting it into navigation controller, this is the issue in your code. You need to cast your `rootViewController` to `MainTabViewController` and then get the selected tab on your `MainTabViewController` if there you have navigation controller then push the `ProductListingVC` controller to that navigation controller else you need to present `ProductListingVC`.

Comment: Yea, you understand the issue, can you please help with a snippet

Comment: I can tell you the way to go: 
1) Get the selected tab on the TabBarController as: `var selectedIndex = tabBarController!.selectedIndex`
2) Now get the selected controller instance as: ` var svc = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[selectedIndex] as UINavigationController!`
3) Now you have the instance of navigation controller and push your view to this controller.

Comment: I just did as you said in the AppDelegate, selectedIndex returns nil
```let rootVc = window?.rootViewController as! MainTabViewController
            let selectedIndex =  rootVc.tabBarController?.selectedIndex```

Comment: I finally solved it, the `tabBarController?` is redundant